# insmod: can't insert 'NetlinkRtLKM.ko': Out of memory

Tags: linux, kernel

I have written a kernel module, compiling and insmod-ing it works perfect on my native linux machine running kernel 5.0.0-36-generic (running as VM).

Now, I want to compile and run the same kernel module for another kernel version 5.0.0.
I have built the kernel version 5.0.0 and installed the kernel modules as below.

```
vm@ubuntu:/usr/lib/modules/5.0.0$ ls -l
total 52
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Nov 24 09:02 build -> /home/vm/Documents/UML/linux-5.0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 24 09:02 kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  566 Nov 24 09:02 modules.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1205 Nov 24 09:02 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4730 Nov 24 09:02 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6949 Nov 24 09:02 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  980 Nov 24 09:02 modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1554 Nov 24 09:02 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 24 09:02 modules.devname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  552 Nov 24 09:02 modules.order
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55 Nov 24 09:02 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1263 Nov 24 09:02 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1357 Nov 24 09:02 modules.symbols.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Nov 24 09:02 source -> /home/vm/Documents/UML/linux-5.0
vm@ubuntu:/usr/lib/modules/5.0.0$
```

I have also updated the makefile to build LKM for right kernel version. Module compiles successfully, but while insmod-ing it into `User Mode Linux` running kernel 5.0.0., getting the error **out of memory**.
WHAT AM I MISSING HERE !!

```
Makefile :
obj-m += NetlinkRtLKM.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0/build ARCH=um M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0/build ARCH=um M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: "out of memory" usually means that you have insufficient memory for perform some operation. It could be that your module requests for memory, and this request fails. But since we don't see your module's code, we couldn't tell more...

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).